# Plugin installation, How to add images?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.3

I'm creating Joomla plugin (3.3 version) and I want to add some images to /images/ folder when installing plugin. Is there a way to add them trough manifest file, or I have to create installation file ?

Comment: You will need to use an install.php script file to move the images upon installation

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely add them through the manifest file the same way you add images to components.

```
<files folder="site">
    <folder>images</folder>
</files>
```

Comment: This install images folder right to the plugin folder. 
Hovewer I need images to be installed to the root folder or even better to images/myfolder.

Comment: Just use a target path. Or do it as media and send to the media folder with a path with your name (you can see some other examples of this if you look in /media).